# Draw Graphs proportional to weight of edges using networkx

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I'm having a Graph to display, but it should be displayed where edges are proportional to the weight. I used networkx library to draw the graph but it draw nodes randomly. 
Here is the part of my code to display graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
# Added nodes and Edges
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(graph, pos=pos, nodelist=nodes, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

How can I create a graph where the edge length is weighted?
If it helps I'm also open to use a different library than matplotlib.

Comment: There might not be a valid layout that satisfies your constraints. Specifically, all your edge weights would have to satisfy the triangle inequality. For example: given the graph `A-B-C-A` the edge weights would need to satisfy: `AB^2 + BC^2 <= AC^2` given that `AB` refers to the edge from `A` to `B` and `AC` is the longest edge. Unless nodes in your graph correspond to geographical locations, your graph potentially won't satisfy these constraints. Is there a good reason not to use the edge color to denote your edge weight?

Comment: why not using edge width instead?

Comment: `spring_layout` has an option that considers weights for the edges.  this won't make it exactly proportional to weights, but it can get you partway there.

Comment: I am trying to cluster the nodes according to the weight. So I was trying to show the nodes of the same cluster together. But I get the point of you. It might not be possible.

Comment: There's only not a valid layout if we assume that edges are straight lines right? What if we remove that assumption and use arcs as close to straight lines as possible?

Comment: I have my own problem where A-B has a weight of 6 but B-A has a weight of 12. I want to represent them in a directed graph not overlapping. I imagine A-B as a straight line, and B-A curved around. Not having much luck working out how to represent as a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The graphviz force directed algorithm outputs what I want. (But I am not sure why it is different than the spring layout from networkx)

```py
import networkx as nx 
import pylab as plt 
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
    
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1) 
G.add_node(2) 
G.add_node(3) 
G.add_node(4)
    
G.add_edge(1,2, len=4.5) 
G.add_edge(2,3, len=2.5) 
G.add_edge(3,4, len=7) 
G.add_edge(4,1, len=10) 
G.add_edge(3,1, len=4.5) 
G.add_edge(4,2, len=9) 

pos=graphviz_layout(G) 
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=1600, node_color=range(len(G)), with_labels=True, cmap=plt.cm.Dark2) 
plt.show()
```

[image: output]